# When dealing with pandas in ipywidgets' interact, can I set a hierarchy for each item?

Tags: python, pandas, ipywidgets

Everyone. I am studying various analysis by dealing with statistical data (mainly csv files).
Recently, I have been interested in and practicing widgets that can be used in Python.

```
@interact
def shop_information       (Commercial_sector_classification_1=list(Cd['Shop_section_1'].unique()),
                            Commercial_sector_classification_2=list(Cd['Shop_section_2'].unique()),
                            Commercial_sector_classification_3=list(Cd['Shop_section_3'].unique())):
                           
                            return Cd[(Cd['Shop_section_1'] == Commercial_sector_classification_1)&
                                      (Cd['Shop_section_2'] == Commercial_sector_classification_2)&
                                      (Cd['Shop_section_3'] == Commercial_sector_classification_3)]
```

This is what I created to filter the information of large, medium, and small classifications.

There is a hierarchy in the commercial sector classification, and it is divided into 1 major category, 2 medium category, and 3 sub category.

By any chance, do you know how to remove from sub-classification other than what was previously filtered by large-classification?